# Hash merge/concatenation

Tags: perl, hash, merge, concatenation

this is a dump of my hashes: %hash1

```
$VAR1 = {
    abc => {
        123 => [
          'xx',
          'yy',
          'zy'
        ],
        456 => [
          'ab',
          'cd',
          'ef'
        ]
    }
};
```

and the second one: %hash2

```
$VAR2 = { 
    def => {
        659 => [
            'wx',
            'yg',
            'kl'
        ],
        456 => [
            'as',
            'sd',
            'df'
        ]
    },
    abc => {
        987 => [
            'lk',
            'dm',
            'sd'
        ]
    }
};
```

Now I want to merge these two hashes in a new hash, but if a key is duplicated (here 'abc'), the values should be appended, not replaced, so the keys should remain unique, and all the values should be retained as well. How can this be done in Perl?
The output should be as follows:

```
$VAR1 = {
    def => {
        659 => [
            'wx',
            'yg',
            'kl'
        ],
        456 => [
            'as',
            'sd',
            'df'
        ]
    },
    abc => {
        987 => [
            'lk',
            'dm',
            'sd'
        ],
        123 => [
            'xx',
            'yy',
            'zy'
        ],
        456 => [
            'ab',
            'cd',
            'ef'
        ]
    }
 };
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of a merged data structure, e.g. between `%a = (key1 => {key2 => [1]})` and `%b = (key1 => {key2 => [1]})`? I don't know which road to take when I don't know where I'm going.

Comment: I have edited the main question with the necessary output, Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for my $x (keys(%h2)) {
    for my $y (keys(%{ $h2{$x} })) {
        push @{ $h1{$x}{$y} }, @{ $h2{$x}{$y} };
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at - line XX`

Comment: @Zaid, I don't get that error, though there is a missing dollar sign. Fixed. I had to rush out without testing, earlier, but the current version is tested.

Comment: @Zaid, Always `use strict; use warnings;` :) ;)

Comment: `strict` and `warnings` don't complain if you use `%h1` instead of `%h2` :)

Comment: I am looking for the same., However, I am not able to figure out where will I write the "print" or the "Dumper" statement to see the output in the solution provide by ikegami. could you help me with the same. thanks.

Comment: @Dheeraj, At the end, of course. And since I'm merging nto `%h1`, it would be `print(Dumper(\%h1));`

Comment: Just a bit curious, what should be done if I want to go one level deeper, so instead of looking at 'abc' or 'def' for matches, how could I look at '659','456' etc. for matches? and instead of merge, lets suppose I want to keep only one of them and remove the rest.

Comment: @ikegami, please see this question I asked about this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674418/perl-compare-and-edit-underlying-structure-in-hash

Answer (score 7):

Use the CPAN modules [`Hash::Merge`](http://p3rl.org/Hash::Merge) or [`Hash::Merge::Simple`](http://p3rl.org/Hash::Merge::Simple). The first is highly configurable and the second is very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub merge_hashes {
    my ($h1, $h2) = @_;
    foreach my $key (keys %$h2) {
        if (!exists $h1->{$key} || ref($h1->{$key}) ne 'HASH' || ref($h2->{$key}) ne 'HASH') {

            $h1->{$key} = $h2->{$key};
        }
        else {
            merge_hashes($h1->{$key}, $h2->{$key});
        }
    }
}

merge_hashes(\%hash1, \%hash2);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sample data provided, the following would perform the merging you describe:

```
my %merged = map {
               $_ => {
                       %{$a{$_} // {}},
                       %{$b{$_} // {}}
                     }
             } ( keys %a, keys %b );
```

Test:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump 'dd';

my %a = (
abc => {
        123 => [
          'xx',
          'yy',
          'zy'
        ],
        456 => [
          'ab',
          'cd',
          'ef'
        ]
    }
);
my %b = (
def => {
        659 => [
            'wx',
            'yg',
            'kl'
        ],
        456 => [
            'as',
            'sd',
            'df'
        ]
    },
    abc => {
        987 => [
            'lk',
            'dm',
            'sd'
        ]
    }
);

my %merged = map {
                   $_ => {
                           %{$a{$_} // {}},
                           %{$b{$_} // {}}
                         }
                 } ( keys %a, keys %b );

dd \%merged;
# {
#   abc => {
#            123 => ["xx", "yy", "zy"],
#            456 => ["ab", "cd", "ef"],
#            987 => ["lk", "dm", "sd"],
#          },
#   def => { 456 => ["as", "sd", "df"], 659 => ["wx", "yg", "kl"] },
# }
```