# Compare and edit underlying structure in hash

Tags: perl, search, hash, structure

I have a hash of complex structure and I want to perform a search and replace. The first hash is like the following:

```
$VAR1 = {
  abc => { 123 => ["xx", "yy", "zy"], 456 => ["ab", "cd", "ef"] },
  def => { 659 => ["wx", "yg", "kl"], 456 => ["as", "sd", "df"] },
  mno => { 987 => ["lk", "dm", "sd"] },
}
```

and I want to iteratively search for all '123'/'456' elements, and if a match is found, I need to do a comparison of the sublayer, i.e. of `['ab','cd','ef']` and `['as','sd','df']` and in this case, keep only the one with ['ab','cd','ef']. So the output will be as follows:

```
$VAR1 = {
  abc => { 123 => ["xx", "yy", "zy"], 456 => ["ab", "cd", "ef"] },
  def => { 659 => ["wx", "yg", "kl"] },
  mno => { 987 => ["lk", "dm", "sd"] },
}
```

So the deletion is based on the substructure, and not index. How can it be done? Thanks for the help!!

Lets assume that I will declare the values to be kept, i.e. I will keep 456 => ["ab", "cd", "ef"] based on a pre-declared value of ["ab", "cd", "ef"] and delete any other instance of 456 anywhere else. The search has to be for every key. so the code will go through the hash, first taking 123 => ["xx", "yy", "zy"] and compare it against the keys throughout the rest of the hash, if no match is found, do nothing. If a match is found, like in the case of 456 => ["ab", "cd", "ef"], it will compare the two, and as I have said that in case of a match the one with ["ab", "cd", "ef"] would be kept, it will keep 456 => ["ab", "cd", "ef"] and discard any other instances of 456 anywhere else in the hash, i.e. it will delete 456 => ["as", "sd", "df"] in this case.

Comment: Take a look at [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).. It is all about these stuffs only..  
Specially `hashes of hashes`

Comment: You should specify how the decision of which entry to keep is supposed to be made.

Comment: You asked me to look at this. All I can say is "What?"

Comment: Asking for your wisdom @ikegami...:) I have edited the question. The 'what' has been defined as 456 => ["ab", "cd", "ef"]. Now my question is how?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses the smart match operator to perform the array comparison:

**Update:** as Borodin pointed out, my original code was wrong.  This is the fixed version.

**Update 2:** Changed it to choose the values to keep based on a hash structure.

```
my $VAR1 = {
  abc => { 123 => ["xx", "yy", "zy"], 456 => ["ab", "cd", "ef"] },
  def => { 659 => ["wx", "yg", "kl"], 456 => ["as", "sd", "df"] },
  mno => { 987 => ["lk", "dm", "sd"] },
};

my %keep_values = (
    '456' => ['ab','cd','ef']
);

foreach my $outer_key (keys %$VAR1)
{
    foreach my $keepers (keys %keep_values)
    {
        if (exists $VAR1->{$outer_key}{$keepers} and 
            #use the smart match operator to compare arrays.
            !(@{$VAR1->{$outer_key}{$keepers}} ~~ @{$keep_values{$keepers}}))
        {
            delete $VAR1->{$outer_key}{$keepers};
        }
    }   
}
```

For more on the smart match operator, see [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator).

Comment: Thanks a lot dan1111, problem is, i need the whole thing to be dynamic, so i cannot define $match_key or @match_array. It needs to be independent of any inputs given by me...

Comment: Then you must clarify what is special about `['ab','cd','ef']` that makes you choose it over `['as','sd','df']`. It's far from obvious

Comment: This is very poor code. You don't have `use strict` or `use warnings` and don't declare `$outer_hash`. Also your variable `$outer_hash` is set to each key of `%$VAR1`, i.e. `abc`, `def`, `mno`, so `$outer_hash->{$match_key}` makes no sense

Comment: @Borodin, alright, lets say I am only keeping ['ab','cd','ef'] and deleting all other instances of the repitition, but I still have to go through all of the keys like '456' and '123' and so on...

Comment: @Borodin, that was a brain dead mistake.  I don't know how it happened; I actually tested this (!), but I must have looked at something wrong.  As for `strict` and `warnings`, yes, I use those, but this is an excerpt, not a complete program.  I have added a `my` declaration to `$outer_hash`, though this is not strictly necessary due to Perl's implicit localization of looping variables.

Comment: @MahfuzurRahmanPallab, you did not define how you want the comparisons to take place.  My aim was to show an example of what you need to do, then you could add your own logic.  If you need further help, you need to better define your question.  It is not clear what "independent of any inputs given by me" means.

Comment: @dan1111 thanks for clarifying the issue, I have edited the question to include the search process. And by Dynamic I meant that the hash is created as part of a script, so although I can possibly edit the condition ["as", "sd", "df"], the keys are unknown to me.

Comment: @MahfuzurRahmanPallab, I updated it to use a structure for the values to keep.  Does this do what you need?

Comment: @dan1111 it almost does. Just that in my case the %keep_values = ['ab','cd','ef']; there might be multiple instances of '123' or '456' under different keys, and when I find multiple '456' instances, I should look for keep_values and keep the one with those values only. If none matches keep_values, I keep all of them.